# Execute linux command as superuser by default

Tags: java, android, linux, rooted-device

I am working on a rooted Android device.
Is there a way to have linux commands executed as superuser without having to invoke

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su")
```

every time? What bothers me is the Toast which appears every time saying that the app has been granted superuser permission. The first time I issue a su command a dialog appears and even if I select to remember the choice every time the command is executed I get the Toast.

Comment: I haven't played around with `su` on Android, but when using it on normal Linux systems, after calling `su` once, you're logged in as the super-user for the rest of the (terminal)-session. So you'll most likely only need to call `su` once for every application-execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope there is no way while using the default su binary as supplied. Both chainxx and chainfire's SU apps have options to not have the popup but thats the users choice.

Of course you could always compile your own su binary and use that, it is open source. This could leave to security concerns having a open su binary, users will probably not like this. If you do you will want to do something like how the other su binaries operate in where its checks to see if it your application doing the calling if not refuse operation. But again this is probably not something you should do.

Comment: Thanks I also came to a similar conclusion. I downloaded an app named Super SU and it had the option you mentioned and after I disabled the Toast  my app did not cause the Toast to appear. So you think these apps have compiled their own su binaries in order to be able to do this?  I certainly don't want to do that as it is probably a complex task and way out of the focus of my app :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want to execute and the frequency. But you can execute more than one command in a OutputStream, so you could queue up your commands in an array or something like that.

```
public void runCommandsAsRoot(String[] cmds) throws IOException {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

    DataOutputStream oStream = new DataOutputStream(proc.getOutputStream());

    for (String cmd : cmds) {
        oStream.writeBytes(cmd + "\n");
    }

    oStream.writeBytes("exit\n");  
    oStream.flush();
}
```

Then invoke it like this:

```
String[] commands = { "fistCommand", "secondCommand" };
runCommandsAsRoot(commands);
```

Comment: Yes thanks this might be useful. My use case requires that I should keep that process running all of the time and execute a few commands every few hours. So what I am thinking is to open the proc on phone startup so the user will see the Toast once only and keep it opened and execute commands when I need to. Can you think of a downside to this approach?

Comment: You need to think about what happens with this Process when your application is suspended or Android is running out of memory and recycles some from your application. I.e. don't try to access a Process when it is null to avoid exceptions. Not sure if Process is prone to leak memory, but there is only one way to find out.